# BCI library for Java in C

Tags: java, c, instrumentation, jvmti, bcel

I am looking for a BCI (Bytecode Instrumentation) library for Java in C or C++, to use in a [JVMTI agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html).

Best case scenario would be something like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) in pure C.

The closest thing I have found so far is only a demo [`java_crw_demo`](https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/a_short_java_crw_demo) written by Kelly O'Hair a few years ago and used in Sun's/Oracle's tutorials ever since.

Do you know of anything else?

> Some rationale: I am building an instrumentation tool to add a getter method to `java.lang.Object` and overload this getter in every direct subclass of `Object`. For this reason I cannot use a Java agent. Also, I would like to avoid spawning a secondary JVM to perform the instrumentation - for complexity and speed reasons.

Comment: It's a good question, but a word of warning on your rationale: you'll find most JVMs don't allow you to instrument j.l.Object.

Comment: Yes they will in a certain limited manner: for example I should be able to add **no more than 1** non-static method in HotSpot. I cannot add any non-static fields there though... 
Therefore I have to resort to the approach above: natively implemented getter in Object, field-implemented overriden getter in subclasses.
(And HotSpot, being the most-used and most-optimized one, is a good benchmark for this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once started writing one in C quite a while ago, but I didn't get very far due to lack of motivation. AFAIK there's no public releases in C, but it shouldn't be too hard to write a simple one for your needs according to the [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html). You should be particularly interested in the chapter on [the `class` file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html), as well as that on [the instruction set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html).

Comment: According to the [laundry list of problems](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kellyohair/archive/2005/05/bytecode_instru.html) found by the author of `java_crw_demo`, I am afraid it could be too hard - even though I am probably aiming for even less changes than Kelly.

Comment: Well, most of those problems involve dealing with raw class files; ideally you should parse them into some easy-to-use representation like [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) and the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) [tree API](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/package-summary.html) attempt to do.

Comment: As the only person who has responded at all, enjoy the points:)

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable solution I have found is to actually pipe the byte codes over to a separate Java program that uses ASM (or the BCI framework of your choice). This is not fast, but you only need to do it once per instrumented class.

Comment: That is precisely the approach taken by the DiSL project http://forge.ow2.org/projects/disl that I actually use :)